# Windows 7 Professional vs Ultimate IIS7 connection limits

Tags: windows-7, iis

is there any difference between simultaneous connections to IIS 7(.5) between Professional and Ultimate versions of Windows 7? Or are there 10 connections for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to see this page: [IIS limits imposed by Operating System version](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm)

```
Windows 7 (IIS v7.5)
Starter:      No IIS  
Home Basic:   No IIS  
Home Premium: simultaneous request execution limit of 3, allows multiple sites  
Business:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites  
Enterprise:   simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites  
Ultimate:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites
```

So, Ultimate version has a limit of 10 whereas Home Premium has 3.

Comment: Thanks! If I get it well, Business = Professional?

Comment: @Episodex: You're welcome. Yeah you're right. Business = Professional.